# if cell equals data from a table, then data from a different column but same row of that table

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

So here's my problem.

Work just told us we're gonna have to fill out a form that used to be annual, quarterly now. so I wanted to make it a little bit easier on us by making the form a bit more automatic.

I know I could just do a nested if statement, but with 20 some-odd people I'd like to avoid that if possible.

```
Here's my idea:

On the main form, there is a place to put your name. I put in a data validation based off a table containing all the names. That table also includes their employee numbers and necessary serial numbers. 

 [![Example Officer Data Table][1]][1]
```

My real question is, how do I write a formula where if the name cell (let's say A1) equals Off 1 1, then it pastes the employee # of 000001, but if A1 equals Off 7 7, then it pastes employee # 000007, and all the other variations, WITHOUT nesting a bunch of ifs. Is that possible? Because I don't just need a code to paste the Employee #, I also need one to paste the Serial # (I realize that I could just nest the ifs for a column over, I just don't want to if there's a more concise way to do it)

Comment: What you describe sounds like you need to use VLOOKUP: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: Without sample data we can't tell VLOOKUP would be the solution, or you need to work with INDEX/MATCH

Comment: @Rami16 thanks for linking that explanation of VLOOKUP, I never understood how to use it before. So for clarity, if I want the main sheet to be variable, would I write the formula as.    =vlookup(A!A1,B!A1:B!B9,2,"")                     to have where A!A1 has the name, & B!A has the possible names & B!B has their employee numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following table, where F1 has data validation coming from A2:A4. Them in F2 I added the formula =VLOOKUP(F1,A2:C4,2) where the 2 means the second column of the interval A2:C4, and in F3 the formula is =VLOOKUP(F1,A2:C4,3)

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said, but then ran into the issue that excel spat out the wrong number every time I changed the search input. I tried adding the FALSE variant, but it said the value was unavailable. I noticed that all your table names were single names, so I guessed using first and last names mucked it up? So I used a modifier block with =RIGHT(F1,LEN(F1)-FIND(" ",F1)) to pull just their last name & it seems to work now. I know we don't currently have employees who share last names, but if that were to happen, how would I use VLOOKUP to differentiate between them, if there's a way to do so?

Comment: That really shouldn't be the case, make sure you are using data validation so the name matches exactly, https://imgur.com/gallery/llTmKvQ you can see it working here

Comment: all that extra ish and my dumb self included the header row in the formula. thanks for checking me 

Comment: If this worked you help everyone by marking the answer as correct :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was working on this while at my security job, so I must've forgotten. Thanks again 